# AS3 Program running on one computer but not other

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, sdk

I have a project in AS3 that is being shared over 2 computers with Dropbox. When I run the program on the computer with CS 5.5, it runs like a charm. However whenever I open it fresh and run it on the computer with CS 4 it asks for a Flex SDK Path, and I hit update library path with the default setting. After this, the program comes up blank and freezes CS 4, forcing me to close the program.

here's the code that I believe causes the problem:

```
[Embed(source="sorted.txt",mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private static const WordFile:Class;
private static var words:Array = new WordFile().toString().split(/\n/);
```

Comment: This question is very confusing.  "When I run **WHAT** program" How do you run something with CS 5.5. You realize that CS5.5 is the arbitrary name for a collection of many products?  "whenever I open **WHAT** fresh and run **WHAT** on the computer with CS4 **WHAT** asks for a Flex SDK Path"?  You hit update library path where?  How does the program come up blank?  What exactly is freezing?

Comment: The CS4 machine does not have the proper Flex SDK installed. And the Application is probably not configured either

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think this has anything to do with your code (which looks alright, and definitely not platform-affecting). The way you describe it, it sounds more like a compiling/debugger error.

My guess is that the two different CS versions cause the problem.

I'd suggest using [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) or another free program, as Flash CS (in any version) is horrible for programmers to say the least. And with a better program, if all programmers/PC use the same version (and the same version of Flex SDK), everything should be alright :)

Comment: Alright. I'll try that and report back later. Hopefully it works!